# Convert doc file to pdf in iphone

Tags: iphone, pdf, .doc

i would like to know is there any way to convert .doc or any file to .pdf file in iphone app.
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct way to do this. The iPhone's UIWebView can parse and display .doc files (and quite a few other formats), so, in theory, you could dump a doc into a webview, grab the onscreen image, and then dump that out to a PDF, but pagination would be tricky.

Comment: hello..as u said i was able to give .doc file to webview. and i am capturing images..but the problem is that i can get only the  onscreen image i.e (only the visible image present in (320,480) my current context).i would like to know how can i get the whole screenshot of uiwebview(i.e the whole .doc file).

Comment: i am also looking for this solution to convert data to pdf format in ipad app